# Cypress throws an assertion error but the result is correct

Tags: cypress, assertion

Cypress throws an assertion error but the result is correct.

Error message:

```
expected 564792 to equal '564792'
```

I have no idea whats wrong with it?!

Does someone has experince with this issue?

Code:

```
// global variables

var value1 = 'global value'
var value2 = 'global value'
var value3 = 'global value'
```

The value for the global variables I get for instance like this:

```
cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(1)').each(($e1, index, $list) => {
        var titletext=$e1.text()
        if(titletext.includes('Some Headline Text')) {
            cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(14)').eq(index).then(function(amount) {
                value1 = amount.text().trim()
            })
        }  
    })
```

This code is the part with the assertion error message:

```
cy.get('#specific_id').then(function(calculation){
        var valueOfCalculation = value1 - value2
        expect (valueOfCalculation).to.equal(value3)
    })
```

With this code above I get the error message, for example:

```
AssertionError
expected 564792 to equal '564792'
```

In other cases with assertions like in this example below the comparison works:

```
expect (value4).to.equal(23040)
```

Any idea what could cause this error?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: Convert valueOfCalculation to a string

```
cy.get('#specific_id').then(function (calculation) {
  var valueOfCalculation = value1 - value2;
  // Convert the numeric value to a string before comparison
  expect(valueOfCalculation.toString()).to.equal(value3);
});
```

Solution 2: Convert value3 to a number

```
cy.get('#specific_id').then(function (calculation) {
  var valueOfCalculation = value1 - value2;
  // Convert the string value to a number before comparison
  expect(valueOfCalculation).to.equal(Number(value3));
});
```